# javascript - strings in a variable to use as condition for if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm making a chart where if person visits a country in a region (in this case Asia), make the bar a certain color.

```
 if (
 d.visitCountry === "China" || d.visitCountry === "Japan" ||
 d.visitCountry === "Afghanistan" || d.visitCountry === "Armenia" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Azerbaijan" || d.visitCountry === "Bangladesh" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Bhutan" || d.visitCountry === "Brunei Darussalam" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Cambodia" || d.visitCountry === "Georgia" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Hong Kong" || d.visitCountry === "India" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Indonesia" || d.visitCountry === "Kazakhstan" || 
 d.visitCountry === "North Korea" || d.visitCountry === "South Korea" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Kyrgyzstan" || d.visitCountry === "Laos" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Macau" || d.visitCountry === "Malaysia" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Maldives" || d.visitCountry === "Mongolia" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Myanmar" || d.visitCountry === "Nepal" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Pakistan" || d.visitCountry === "Singapore" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Sri Lanka" || d.visitCountry === "Taiwan" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Tajikistan" || d.visitCountry === "Thailand" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Timor Leste" || d.visitCountry === "Turkmenistan" || 
 d.visitCountry === "Uzbekistan" || d.visitCountry === "Vietnam") {
     returnColor = "red";
 }
```

The problem with this method I'm using is it's long and tedious.

Is there any way to make it so it's something like this

```
var worldRegion = {
 worldRegion.Asia = [ China, Japan, North Korea ... ]
 worldRegion.northAmerica = [USA, Canada, Greenland ... ]
 worldRegion.Africa = [ ... ]

if (d.visitCountry === worldRegion.Asia) /* this is obviously wrong */ {
        returnColor = "red";
}
else if (d.visitCountry === worldRegion.northAmerica) /* this is obviously wrong */ {
        returnColor = "blue";
}
return returnColor;
```

Obviously that code is wrong though.

Comment: Please format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do what you're talking about with a bunch of arrays, but I'd probably use an object as a map instead:

```
var countryColors = {
    China: "red",
    Japan: "red",
    "North Korea": "red",
    // ...
    USA: "blue",
    Canada: "blue",
    Greenland: "blue"
};
```

Note that properties that have valid literal names can be written literally, but ones that don't have valid literal names (like North Korea, because of the space) are put in quotes. Or you can put them all in quotes for consistency.

Then

```
returnColor = countryColors[d.visitCountry];
```

But if you want to do it with a bunch of arrays, use `Array#indexOf`: If the result is not `-1`, the entry is there:

```
if (worldRegion.Asia.indexOf(d.visitCountry) !== -1) {
    returnColor = "red";
}
else if (worldRegion.northAmerica.indexOf(d.visitCountry !== -1) {
    returnColor = "blue";
}
// ...
```

---

Side note: If you need to support obsolete browsers like IE8, you may need a shim (polyfill) for `Array#indexOf`. A search will turn one up. All modern browsers have it built-in.

---

<s>Side note: I'm pretty sure Greenland isn't in North America.</s> What do you know, [I'm wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenland) about that...

Comment: I solved the problem with your second solution - with a bunch of arrays - because that saves time with typing the colors all over again for each country. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object map to "lookup" the color for a given country name:

```
var colorMap = {
    "China": "red",
    "Japan": "red",
    // fill in other countries and colors here
    "USA": "blue"
};

function getColor(country) {
    var color = colorMap[country];
    if (!color) {
        // default color
        color = "black";
    }
    return color;
}
```

By adding a little more complexity to the code, you could group them by color too:

```
var colorMap = {
    red: ["China", "Japan", "North Korea"],
    blue: ["USA", "Canada", "Greenland"],
    yellow: ["Kenya", "Egypt"]

};

function getColor(country) {
    for (var color in colorMap) {
        if (colorMap[color].indexOf(country) !== -1) {
            return color;
        }
    }
    return "black";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do something like what you have done. Below is the working sample for your problem.

```
function GetColorBasedOnCountry(visitCountry) {
        var worldRegion = { Asia: ["China", "Japan", "North Korea", "India"],
            northAmerica: ["USA", "Canada", "Greenland"],
            Africa: ["SouthAfrica", "Zimbabwe"]
        };

        var returnColor = "";
        if (worldRegion.Asia.indexOf(visitCountry) > -1) {
            returnColor = "red";
        }
        else if (worldRegion.northAmerica.indexOf(visitCountry) > -1) {
            returnColor = "blue";
        }
        else
            returnColor = "green";

        return returnColor;
    }
```

Comment: Works perfectly similar to TJ's reply. Thank you!